# How to change Default Date Format in JFormattedTextField with Mask in netbeans

Tags: date, datetime, netbeans

I am trying to change Default Date Format in JFormattedTextField with mask.

I have masking but it is getting default date format (MM/dd/YYYY) but I want to change it to (dd/MM/YYYY). How can I do this?

Here is my code for JFormattedTextField

```
txt_RStart = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
try {
txt_RStart.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####")));
} catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

this code provides (MM/dd/YYYY) this date format by default but need (dd/MM/YYYY) this date Fromat
How can I add dateformat with this mask?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give the format while initializing the textfield as given in the snippet below:

`DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
txt_Rstart = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(format);`